# SP2013 Remote Event Receivers won't fire on local premises provider-hosted app

Tags: 2013

I have been trying for nearly a week now to get a remote list item event receiver to fire in SP2013.  I have VS2012 RTM installed in Windows 7 (also tried with RC) and I am deploying remotely to a LAN install of SP2013 Preview on Server 2008 R2 VM.

I have tried to run the BasicDataOperations test project but I can't get it to deploy for some reason.  However I have created my own project following along with the video here: http://www.bing.com/videos/watch/video/remote-event-receivers-in-sharepoint-2013-demo/10ty138ca?cpkey=57522630-78e7-407a-9ab8-eef00a63580d%7C%7C%7C%7C.

Everything is setup exactly the same as demonstrated in the video and I can deploy the project and add items to the list but the events just never fire.  I have copied in the items from BasicDataOperations but had the same results.

I have used ItemAdded and ItemAdding and it has never fired my event handler code which just inserts a record into a table in a db on the SharePoint SQL server.  I have also tried other  code in the handlers like inserting a record into a different list.  I have tried and retried every little tweak and change but no luck. I'm not getting any error messages and I have searched and searched in the logs but haven't seen anything related.

I'm sure I'm overlooking something here but my ego has me convinced there is some kind of notorious Microsoft "bug/feature" at work here.  Has anyone gotten this to work?

Answer (score 1):

Answer(s) here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/appsforsharepoint/thread/ff78c575-27a8-4561-93ac-a6a440908871

Comment: Would be best practice on sharepoint.stackexchange to copy your answer into here as well.